# Customizing bootstrap 3 sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm having problems customizing bootstrap 3 sass. _variables.scss is my problem. My setup is this:

```
- scss
  -- bootstrap
  -- template
     bootstrap.scss
     template.scss
```

Bootstrap.scss will create the default bootstap. Template.scss creates the template I need. The problem is _variables.scss in the bootstrap folder. When I set $font-size-base in template/_variables.scss, it's overwritten by _variables.scss in bootstrap/_variables.

The template.scss has this in it:

```
import "template/my_variables.scss"
import "_bootstrap.scss" 
// to import bootstrap but I want to keep bootstrap separated from the template
... all other partials for this template
```

I can solve this by removing the _variables.scss in bootstrap. But I don't think it's a good idea to do that. I don't want to touch the bootstrap if possible. *(Don't hack the core!)*

I can also solve this by making bootstrap.scss a partial in template.scss. That's the best solution, but for this template I need a bootstrap.min.css together with template.css.

What's the best way to customize bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you make a .scss file that only consists of imports. You could call it style.scss. You'll only need to write import statements in this file. For example:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome";

@import "myVariables";
@import "myMixins";
@import "myTemplate"

@import "navbar";
@import "header";
@import "footer";
```

The order in which you write the import statements determines what gets overwritten. If you set a variable in myVariables and import myVariables below Bootstrap, as in the example, then your variable will overwrite the Bootstrap variable. You'll also only have to compile this file (style.scss) into css.

Comment: This works, but is bootstrap 4 solution. Bootstrap 3 does not have the partial _bootstrap.scss in it.